# Use PowerShell to send message to a window Control

Tags: c#, powershell, user32

How to use powershell send a message to a window Control? I have a send example under C#, but I don't know how to write code in powershell.

```
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern IntPtr SendMessageS(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, string lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

static void TestQm2SendMessage()
{
    var hwnd = FindWindow("QM_Editor", null);
    if(hwnd == default(IntPtr)) return;
    SendMessageS(hwnd, 12, 1, "Q ' M 'Macro295' C test C#");
}
```

I tried to convert C# code to powershell code, but it didn't work. Any suggestions are welcome

```
$code = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageW", CharSet =  CharSet.Unicode)] public static extern IntPtr SendMessageS(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, string lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
'@
$myAPI = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Name myAPI -PassThru
$myAPI::SendMessageS($myAPI::FindWindow("QM_Editor", $Null), 12, 1, "Q ' M 'Macro295' C test C#");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found on the Internet

```
    function Out-Notepad
    {
      param
      (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [String]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        $Text
      )
     
      begin
      {
        $sb = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
      }
     
      process
      {
        $null = $sb.AppendLine($Text)
      }
      end
      {
        $text = $sb.ToString()
     
        $process = Start-Process notepad -PassThru
        $null = $process.WaitForInputIdle()
     
     
        $sig = '
          [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")] public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
          [DllImport("User32.dll")] public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
        ' 
     
        $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name APISendMessage -PassThru
        $hwnd = $process.MainWindowHandle
        [IntPtr]$child = $type::FindWindowEx($hwnd, [IntPtr]::Zero, "Edit", $null)
        $null = $type::SendMessage($child, 0x000C, 0, $text)
      }
    } 
    #Get-Content -Path 'С:\Folder\File.txt' | Out-String | Out-Notepad
    'Send this text to Notepad' | Out-Notepad
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [.NET System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?view=netframework-4.8). This will also work in Powershell.

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Your message here!", 'This is my title', 'YesNo', 'Information')
```

Comment: Hello, the message I mentioned is to the controls, I need to convert the above C# code to powershell code